# Unexpected if(T_IF) parser error

Tags: php

Unexpected if(T_IF) on line 15, I know it is probably something I'm not closing, and maybe I have just been staring at the screen too long but I can't find it.

```
 <?php

$response=array();


if (!empty($_GET["page"])){
    $Page = $_GET['page'];
    $limit= (int)page*10;

      $db = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'CampusList') or die(mysqli_error());
// get all products from products table
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM post order by post_date desc limit $limit") or die(mysqli_error());
 

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // looping through all results
    // products node
    $response["post"] = array();
 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        // temp user array
        $post = array();
        $post["post_id"] = $row["post_id"];
        $post["post_name"] = $row["post_name"];
        $post["post_creator"] = $row["post_creator"];
        $post["post_type"] = $row["post_type"];
        $post["post_school_id"] = $row["post_school_id"];
        $post["post_content"] = $row["post_content"];
        $post["price"] = $row["price"];
        $post["post_date"] = $row["post_date"];
        $post["post_class_id"] = $row["post_class_id"];
        $post["post_flagged"] = $row["post_flagged"];
 
        // push single product into final response array
        array_push($response["post"], $post);
    }
    // success
    $response["success"] = 1;
 
    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // no products found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No Posts found";
 
    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}
}else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Error Please try again";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Ths is just a php activated script to return 10 entries from a database, nothing fancy, yes for some reason I am not catching what is causing this error, thank you for the help!

Comment: Might be this `$limit= (int)page*10;` missing the `$` in front of the word `page`. Do `$limit= (int)$page*10;` yet that should be upper-case `P` as in `$limit= (int)$Page*10;` but am not 100% sure about that.

Comment: But this `mysql_num_rows` should be `mysqli_num_rows` is the most important one; missing the `i`. You can't mix `mysql_` with `mysqli_` functions. and `mysql_fetch_array` to `mysqli_fetch_array`

Comment: This is not related to your problem, but you should also remove the space in the `<?php` line (if you really have it in your script file)

Comment: that was a stupid mistake but sadly not the fix!(thank you for saving me a future error though haha)

Comment: I edited one of my comment about `mysql_fetch_array` so do => `mysqli_fetch_array`

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` during development. This will signal any errors found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% this is the solution, but I reformatted & looked through your code. Here is what I have. First, you have `(int)page*10;` which contextually makes no sense. So I changed that to `(int) $Page*10;` but that could probably be just `intval($Page*10);`. Also you are using `mysql_num_rows` when it should probably be `mysqli_num_rows`. So adjusted that as well.

```
$response=array();


if (!empty($_GET["page"])) {
    $Page = $_GET['page'];
    // $limit= intval($Page*10); // Maybe this would work as well.
    $limit= (int) $Page*10;

    $db = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'CampusList') or die(mysqli_error());
    // get all products from products table
    $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM post order by post_date desc limit $limit") or die(mysqli_error());


    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        // looping through all results
        // products node
        $response["post"] = array();

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            // temp user array
            $post = array();
            $post["post_id"] = $row["post_id"];
            $post["post_name"] = $row["post_name"];
            $post["post_creator"] = $row["post_creator"];
            $post["post_type"] = $row["post_type"];
            $post["post_school_id"] = $row["post_school_id"];
            $post["post_content"] = $row["post_content"];
            $post["price"] = $row["price"];
            $post["post_date"] = $row["post_date"];
            $post["post_class_id"] = $row["post_class_id"];
            $post["post_flagged"] = $row["post_flagged"];

            // push single product into final response array
            array_push($response["post"], $post);
        }
        // success
        $response["success"] = 1;

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    else {
        // no products found
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No Posts found";

        // echo no users JSON
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}
else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Error Please try again";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the fixes, apologies for my sloppiness, but this still isn't my fix :/

Comment: ended up having to retype the entire damn code, it was a phantom, somewhere around line 14, still cant see it but retyped it char for char and it works

Comment: sorry jake, new to the site, I can't upvote yet, but I ended up having to retype the file(it was something invisible that copy/pasted over, but when i retyped it worked!) So thank you I checked this as the answer

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the `$` in front of `page` and that should be an upper-case `P` since you're using it with `$Page` in `$Page = $_GET['page'];`

PHP variables are case-sensitive.

You're also mixing MySQL APIs, they don't mix together.

`mysql_num_rows` should be `mysqli_num_rows` and `mysql_fetch_array` should be `mysqli_fetch_array`

```
<?php

$response=array();


if (!empty($_GET["page"])){
    $Page = $_GET['page'];
    $limit= (int)$Page*10;

      $db = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'CampusList') or die(mysqli_error());
// get all products from products table
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM post order by post_date desc limit $limit") or die(mysqli_error());


if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // looping through all results
    // products node
    $response["post"] = array();

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        // temp user array
        $post = array();
        $post["post_id"] = $row["post_id"];
        $post["post_name"] = $row["post_name"];
        $post["post_creator"] = $row["post_creator"];
        $post["post_type"] = $row["post_type"];
        $post["post_school_id"] = $row["post_school_id"];
        $post["post_content"] = $row["post_content"];
        $post["price"] = $row["price"];
        $post["post_date"] = $row["post_date"];
        $post["post_class_id"] = $row["post_class_id"];
        $post["post_flagged"] = $row["post_flagged"];

        // push single product into final response array
        array_push($response["post"], $post);
    }
    // success
    $response["success"] = 1;

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // no products found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No Posts found";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}
}else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Error Please try again";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```